# Weird background glitch when using animation on the page in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

If i have an animated element followed by another non-animated element, banding effect and various color shifting bugs appear in Chrome. Hard to see, but i recorded a video(if you zoom in on the page, the color shifts, easier to see): https://d26dzxoao6i3hh.cloudfront.net/items/1w1k2e3v0g04142U2A3H/Screen%20Recording%202017-10-30%20at%2011.35%20PM.mov

```css
header {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #263238;
 }
 
 header a {
  animation: scroll-down-anim 1s infinite;
 }

@keyframes scroll-down-anim {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#">Animated element</a>
 </header>
 <p>if i remove this, the glitch disappears</p>
```

Any ideas how to fix this? If i remove the `<p>` element, it works. Also works on any other browser, like Safari.

Comment: What version of Chrome? This is working fine for me in Chrome 61, OS X.

Comment: Have you tried `translate3d`?

Answer (score 0):

Well this actually works for me, so I strongly suspect that it's just your graphics card or version of Chrome that's having issues.

However I would suggest that the reason it's happening is that the `translate` style forces Chrome to render using the GPU and having the P tag there is giving it a hard time.

If you were to force the P tag to use the same translation too then that might fix the issue for you, like this:

```
p {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**it has nothing to do with chrome or your codes**

Its your gpu ! specially if you have a m series Gpu (laptop to be exact)

so what happens is when you're using a ratio or a resolution higher or lower than your monitors native settings you put too much pressure on the gpu !

Update your graphics software by the os itself or bring the resolution back to its factory resolution